# Making sure drawImage draws the image on HTML5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, drawimage

I am making a multiple choice quiz game for canvas, where users upload their own images for multiple choice answers.

When the next question is selected, the variables for the next question are got from a javascript array, including filepath for the image.

The problem I am having with this is that usually on the first quiz attempt, images sometimes do not load in time to be drawn on the canvas. I am trying to improve the performance of the canvas side of the quiz, by ensuring image answers are always drawn.

Help would be greatly appreciated. The code for drawing images on canvas is below.

```
//else if answer type is image answer
    else if(answertype == "image"){
        answerbg.src = "./resources/imageaudiovideoanswerbg.png";
        eventstate = 'imageaget';
        if (answerbg.complete) {
        context.drawImage(answerbg, 0, 280);
            context.drawImage(imagefilea,75,285);
            context.drawImage(imagefileb,375,285);
            context.drawImage(imagefilec,75,591);
            context.drawImage(imagefiled,375,591);
        } 
        else {
               answerbg.onload = function () {
               context.drawImage(answerbg, 0, 280);  
               context.drawImage(imagefilea,75,285);
               context.drawImage(imagefileb,375,285);
               context.drawImage(imagefilec,75,591);
               context.drawImage(imagefiled,375,591);
                };
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to make sure that the image is loaded before you can draw it on canvas.

So what you would have to do is somthing like:

```
var image = new Image(); //make a new image object
image.onload = function() { //when the image has loaded...
doStuffWithImage(); //Do somthing with it (draw it on canvas etc.)
}
image.src = '/your/path/image.png'; //set the source (afterwards!)
```

This is something you have to know if your working with images and canvas.

Also if you have trouble loading all the images make a `preLoadAllImagesfromSource(sourceArray)` function, where all the images objects are allready preloaded when the main code is executed.

Hope that helped.

Comment: Sorry for the delay, implemented this, images tend to load most times, but sometimes fail. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can consider embedding the image and/or other resources using BASE64 encoding in the JavaScript or the HTML itself.

http://ejohn.org/blog/embedding-and-encoding-in-javascript/

Of course in your case since it is a user uploaded content, you may have to generate the JavaScript from the uploaded image.